# Arduino - Sending a GET request to a server, get 200 OK but no additional response

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm working on an Arduino project (Arduino Mega 2560). I'm using the library uartWIFI, and I can successfully send a GET request to my server. The page I'm connecting to is supposed to echo "test" when you GET it, but the output is empty.

Here is my HTTP-connection code in the Arduino:

```cpp
void httpRequest() {
  // if there's a successful connection:
  if (wifi.ipConfig(TCP,server, 80)) 
  {
        
    Serial.println("-----------");
    DebugSerial.println("connecting...");
    
    
    
    // send the HTTP PUT request:
    // We now create a URI for the request
    String url = "/a.php?";
    url += "name=test";
    Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);
  
    
    wifi.Send("GET " + url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
    // note the time that the connection was made:
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
  } 
  else 
  {
    // if you couldn't make a connection:
    DebugSerial.println("connection failed");
    DebugSerial.println("disconnecting.");
    wifi.closeMux();
  }
}
```

The output I'm expecting is "test", but here is the response I get back, as printed to the serial monitor.
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIFNg.png)

When I curl the URL, I get the expected response.

EDIT: Added the rest of the code, when the function i posted earlier gets called

```cpp
void loop()
{
    
  char message[320];
   // if you're not connected, and ten seconds have passed since
  // your last connection, then connect again and send data:
  if((millis() - lastConnectionTime > postingInterval)) {
    httpRequest();
  } 
  // if there's incoming data from the net connection.
  // send it out the serial port.  This is for debugging
  // purposes only:
  delay(1000);
  if(wifi.ReceiveMessage(message)) 
  {
      Serial.println("Receive: ");
      DebugSerial.println(message);   
  }

  delay(100);

}
```